# Date on invoice?

Tags: invoices

I'm a bit confused about the date that I need to put on my invoice.
I'm getting paid on the 1st day of the month.

So I did some work on March.

1. When should I send the invoice? March 31th or April 1st?
2. When should the due date be (I have net 30). April 30th?
3. So basically should I be generating an invoice for the previous month's work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- the invoice date: last day of the previous month when work was completed (March 31)
- send invoice the same/next day (March 31 OR April 1st) doesn't make a difference
- yes: invoice is always generated after work is completed unless otherwise agreed upon.  (in case of multi month project OR pre-payment arrangement)

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! What about the due date?

Comment: @JamesKroning I generally don't put due dates directly on invoices. I put "Payment is due upon receipt" and my contract states payment is due Net 15 (Many use Net 30 though). So the invoice would also have "Net 15 days" on it. The date of the invoice itself serves as a "start of the clock" essentially.